# Is there a good upper ground to the number of digits of a factorial n! when I only know the number of digits of $n$?

Tags: factorial

I was coding a function for calculating the factorial of a big number in $C$. Since I'm using a structure where I don´t know directly the value of the number, I need to find the number of digits of the result (or a decent upper bound) only knowing the number of digits of my original number. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is it a possibility to dynamically resize your structure at runtime (eg double the number of digits whenever the structure fills up)? That seems like the easiest way to prevent overallocating too much memory to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a natural number $n$, the number of decimal digits is equal to $d(n)=\lfloor \log_{10}(n)\rfloor +1$. If you only know the value of $d(n)$, then $n$ could be as large as the number consisting of $d(n)$ nines $999...9$, or $10^{d(n)}-1$. This means that the best upper bound we can get on the number of digits of $n!$ given only the number of digits of $n$ is equal to
$$d(n!)\le d\big((10^{d(n)}-1)!\big)$$
and this is a tight bound. Let’s see if we can simplify this a bit to get an upper bound that is easier to calculate but a little bit less tight. First of all, note that $d(n) < \log_{10}(n)+1$, so we have
$$d(n!)\le \log_{10}\big((10^{d(n)}-1)!\big)+1$$
Now, a companion to [Stirling’s Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) tells us that $N!$ is less than or equal to $N^{N+1/2}e^{1-N}$ for all natural numbers $N$. Thus, we have from the above inequality that
$$d(n!)\le \frac{10^{d(n)}-1/2}{\ln(10)}\ln(10^{d(n)}-1)+\frac{2-10^{d(n)}}{\ln(10)}+1$$
This is decent, but it’s still a bit ugly. Let’s cut out some unnecessary terms (while preserving inequality) to get the following nicer (but still less tight) upper bound:
$$d(n!)\le d(n)\cdot 10^{d(n)}-\frac{10^{d(n)}}{\ln(10)}$$
This formula should work for $n\ge 4$, say.